# Cannot Find Function In Object

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, prototype

I'm developing a Google Sheets application to replace my subscription task manager. The Script works for daily, weekly, bimonthly, quarterly, semiannually, and yearly. The Script fails for "Every Weekday" with the error:

> TypeError: Cannot find function add in object Mon Dec 28 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST). (line 69, file "Code").

The prototype function seems to work fine in the daily, weekly, etc. sections of the code but bombs in the "Every Weekday" section. I've tried moving the prototype function into different sections to no avail.

The structure of the Sheet is as follows:

- Each row represents a discrete task
- Column A = "X" indicates the task is complete
- Column C describes the task
- Column I contains the repeat date as mm/dd/yyyy
- Column K contains the repeat type (daily, weekly, etc.)
  [image: screenshot]

Here is my code:

```js
// Declare global variables
var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var lRow = ws.getLastRow();
var lCol = ws.getLastColumn()
var range = ws.getRange(lRow, 1, 2, lCol);

// Create Custom menu in worksheet
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom')
    .addItem('Complete Current Task', 'compTask')
    .addItem('Duplicate Task', 'dupeTask')
    .addItem('Re-sort', 'customSort')
    .addToUi();
}

function compTask() {

  var booFound; //declares booFound as False
  var actRow = ws.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var dateDue = ws.getRange('I' + actRow).getValue();
  var strRepeat = ws.getRange('K' + actRow).getValue();
  var dateRepeat = new Date();
  var dateNow = new Date();

  if (strRepeat == 'Daily') {
    booFound = true;
    dateRepeat = dateDue.add("d", 1);
  }

  if (strRepeat == 'Weekly') {
    booFound = true;
    dateRepeat = dateDue.add("d", 7);
  }

  if (strRepeat == 'Biweekly') {
    booFound = true;
    dateRepeat = dateDue.add("d", 14);
  }

  if (strRepeat == 'Monthly') {
    booFound = true;
    dateRepeat = dateDue.add("mo", 1);
  }

  if (strRepeat == 'Bimonthly') {
    booFound = true;
    dateRepeat = dateDue.add("mo", 2);
  }

  if (strRepeat == 'Quarterly') {
    booFound = true;
    dateRepeat = dateDue.add("mo", 3);
  }

  if (strRepeat == 'Semiannually') {
    booFound = true;
    dateRepeat = dateDue.add("mo", 6);
  }

  if (strRepeat == 'Yearly') {
    booFound = true;
    dateRepeat = dateDue.add("y", 1);
  }

  if (strRepeat == 'Every Weekday') {
    booFound = true;
    if (dateDue.getDay() < 5) {
      dateRepeat = dateDue.add("d", 1);
    } else {
      dateRepeat = dateDue.add("d", 8);
      var dayNumber = dateDue.getDay();
      dayNumber = ~dayNumber + 1;
      dateRepeat = dateRepeat.add("d", dayNumber);
    }
  }

  if (booFound) {
    var range = ws.getRange(actRow, 1, 1, lCol);
    ws.insertRowsAfter(actRow, 1);
    range.copyTo(ws.getRange(actRow + 1, 1, 1, lCol), {
      contentsOnly: false
    });
    ws.getRange('A' + actRow).setValue('X');
    ws.getRange('J' + actRow).setValue(dateNow);
    ws.getRange('I' + (actRow + 1)).setValue(dateRepeat);
  } else {
    ws.getRange('A' + actRow).setValue('X');
    ws.getRange('J' + actRow).setValue(dateNow);
  }

}

Date.prototype.add = function(sInterval, iNum) {
  var dTemp = this;
  if (!sInterval || iNum == 0) return dTemp;
  switch (sInterval.toLowerCase()) {
    case "ms":
      dTemp.setMilliseconds(dTemp.getMilliseconds() + iNum);
      break;
    case "s":
      dTemp.setSeconds(dTemp.getSeconds() + iNum);
      break;
    case "mi":
      dTemp.setMinutes(dTemp.getMinutes() + iNum);
      break;
    case "h":
      dTemp.setHours(dTemp.getHours() + iNum);
      break;
    case "d":
      dTemp.setDate(dTemp.getDate() + iNum);
      break;
    case "mo":
      dTemp.setMonth(dTemp.getMonth() + iNum);
      break;
    case "y":
      dTemp.setFullYear(dTemp.getFullYear() + iNum);
      break;
  }
  return dTemp;

}

function customSort() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var allData = sheet.getDataRange();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, allData.getNumRows() - 1, allData.getNumColumns());
  range.sort([1, 9, 12]);
  ws.setActiveCell(ws.getRange(2, 1));
}

function dupeTask() {
  var actRow = ws.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var range = ws.getRange(actRow, 1, 1, lCol);
  ws.insertRowsAfter(actRow, 1);
  range.copyTo(ws.getRange(actRow + 1, 1, 1, lCol), {
    contentsOnly: false
  });
}
```

[image: compTask run in debugger showing variable types.]

Comment: Check the format of the that particular cell. It looks like that particular cell is not recognized as date but as string. Try using the debugger, it tells what kind of value is contained in the variable.

Comment: In addition to @Gerado's solution, you could format the value using the date constructor. So: var dateDue = new Date(...getValue()); JavaScript will interpret the string or number it's given and return a date object.

Comment: Geraldo & Jens, thank you for your comments.  I ran compTask on the debugger and it confirmed that the values being passed to add are indeed date variables.  The mystery is why does add work for every selection other than "Every Weekday" since it is passed the same variables?

Comment: I edited my original post to include an image of the debugger run.  See "compTask run in debugger showing variable types" above.

Comment: Does this happen only for that date or for all dates?

Comment: Robin, if you are asking whether it matters what date value is passed to the routine, it does not.  Regardless of date the other selections will run without complaint and "Every Weekday" will error out.

Comment: dayNumber = ~dayNumber + 1; Why is there a tilde prior to dayNumber after the equal sign

Comment: ScampMichael, that was something I gleaned from researching various JS forums.  Supposedly it will produce the same result as dayNumber = (dayNumber * -1) + 1; though I obviously haven't been able to evaluate that yet.

Comment: As dayNumber shows undefined in the above I think I would rewrite that without the tilde to see what happens.

Comment: ScampMichael, I reordered the lines of code in the function beginning at line 71:
71  var dayNumber = dateDue.getDay(); // evaluates to dayNumber = 5.0
72  dayNumber = ~dayNumber + 1; // evaluates to dayNumber = -5.0 as expected
73  dateRepeat = dateDue.add("d", 8); // produces the error I am trying to resolve

dayNumber was undefined in the image because the associated var hadn't executed,

Comment: I take it everyone is stumped?

Comment: I've continued to try different approaches to a resolution since no suggestions have been offered regarding the central issue.  In the latest I changed the offending code (beginning at line 66) with the following to remove any concerns:
    if (strRepeat == 'Every Weekday') {
      booFound = true;
      var dayNumber = dateDue.getDay();
      if (dayNumber < 5) {
        dateRepeat = dateDue.add("d", 1);
      } else {
        dayNumber = (dayNumber * -1) + 1;
        dateRepeat = dateDue.add("d", 8); 
        dateRepeat = dateRepeat.setDate(dateRepeat.getDate() + dayNumber);
      } 
   }